# How to extend a Textfield that is allready on the stage in Flash (AS3)?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, textfield

I'm looking for a way to extend a TextField that's allready on the stage in Flash (AS3)
something like this:

```
public class ChildTextField extends TextField 
{
    //code for childTextField comes here    
}
```

I've placed a TextField with instance name 'thetextfield' on the stage. Now I would like to tell flash this textfield is of type ChildTextField. So in my Document Class I declare that textfield as a ChildTextField:

```
public class DocumentClass extends Sprite()
{
    public var thetextfield : ChildTextField;
}
```

This throws a Type Coercion failed Error. 
Is it possible to change the class that is used for a textfield in the Flash IDE like you can do with library symbols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afraid not. You will have to use ActionScript if you want to add your extended textfield class.

EDIT: there is a hack way. source: http://board.flashkit.com/board/archive/index.php/t-738887.html

> Actually, I've run into this exact
>   problem before. In my case, I was
>   trying to create a textfield with
>   extra behaviors for other some other
>   non-coder artists to use. I'll tell
>   you my original solution which is all
>   as3, but had a fatal flaw, and my
>   current solution, which is a
>   combination of as3 and jsfl.
>
> The all as3 solution is great except
>   for 2 things: First, it happens at
>   runtime rather than build-time. That
>   means there's a small but real portion
>   of time where the movie isn't
>   correctly initialized. Second, it does
>   not play well if there are multiple
>   frames in the movie. The basic idea is
>   to detect the TextFields you want to
>   change, build things to replace them
>   with, then replace them on stage. You
>   can do this with either by extending
>   TextField, or building a class which
>   contains a TextField and handles the
>   interface to it. Let's say you're
>   doing the first. Add a constructor to
>   SmartTextField that copies all the
>   fields you care about:

```
public function SmartTextField(TextField tf)
{
this.text = tf.text; //continue with copy of anything relevant. 
}
```

> in your main movie have code which
>   detects and replaces the TextFields
>   you want to replace

```
 var toreplace:Array = findTextFields(); 
 var tf:TextField;
 var stf:SmartTextField; 
 var where:int;
 for (int i = 0; i < toreplace.length;i++)
 { tf = TextField(toreplace[i]);
   stf = new SmartTextField(tf); 
   where = getChildIndex(tf); 
    addChildAt(stf,where); 
    removeChild(tf); 
 }
```

> This works fine, except for the points
>   above.
>
> The JSFL solution is a bit too complex
>   to go over in detail, but here's the
>   basics. Have an as3 class which wraps
>   a textfield with the new behavior you
>   want. Write a jsfl script which
>   iterates over the selected items, and
>   if it's a textfield, converts to a
>   symbol with a baseclass of your new
>   wrapper class. This has the advantages
>   that it happens at author time, and
>   things like position, instancename and
>   other stuff is automatically
>   preserved. It has the disadvantage
>   that jsfl has a lot of little annoying
>   quirks to work through.
>
> edit: Of course, if this is only for a
>   single movie, you could forego the
>   jsfl converter script, and just do it
>   by hand. convert to symbol -> wrapper
>   baseclass.

Comment: Thanks for all your useful information Allan,

I think for my purpose, the easiest way would be to create a wrapper class containing a Textfield and adding the functionality to the Wrapper instead of the TextField. 

I think it Would be a nice feature to be able to change all stage object's base classes in a future Flash version. 

Maybe in CS5 ....

Comment: yes that is a good idea :). Hopefully CS5 delivers some additions and improvements.